Determine change in sets of numbers (frequencies) over time
I am looking for a statistical test that allows me to calculate whether or not there has been a statistically significant change in a set of numbers, specifically frequencies.
Imagine that, across 5 different school districts, I check whether, for each classroom in the district, there is at least one student named "Ted". I then collect the number of classes with at least one "Ted" and divided by the number of classes. I do this for every classroom, obtaining a set such as [0.02, 0.002, 0.004, 0.003, 0.00001]. I then repeat this operation every year, obtaining such data for every year for 20 years.
I would like to know a test that allows me to check if one year is significantly different from the previous one(s). I had a couple of ideas in mind:

Kolmogorov–Smirnov test: if I treated the frequencies as coming all from the same probability distribution, this would be acceptable, I think. However, I am not sure such an assumption is warranted.
CUMSUM: this came up a lot in my research, but I am not fully sure it applies here.

My main issue is that I have never dealt with issues like this so I am not confident I am overlooking better methods or that they are doing what I want them to do.
Any information on how to implement the tests and calculate the results in Python (or R) (even just the package name you recommend), would also be very appreciated.

Suppose you want to check whether this year appears to be consistent with the previous year's distribution.  Then you can build a 2x2 contingency table, with the column indicating whether the data came from last year or this year, and the row indicating whether you are counting the number of Teds or non-Teds, and a count in each cell of the corresponding number of students.  The question becomes whether there is any statistically significant association between rows vs columns.
One solution is to use Fisher's exact test to compute a p-value for the null hypothesis that there is no association.  If the p-value is below the significance threshold, then you conclude that there has apparently been a change since last year.  (Another alternative to Fisher's exact test is to use a permutation test.  Either should be perfectly sufficient in practice.)
For comparing to multiple prior years, you need to figure out what you want to use as the reference distribution.  One approach is to have a column for this year and another column for the aggregation of all prior years. Make sure to use counts rather than percentages in the contingency table.
Beware of making multiple comparisons, if you are repeating this test for each year in your dataset.  Depending on how you are using this,  you might consider applying a Bonferroni correction.
Ultimately, your question is a matter of statistics (or data science), not computer science.
